# Class 'ZendSearch\Lucene\Lucene' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, lucene, zend-framework2

related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667675/zendsearch-install-with-composer-class-zendsearch-lucene-lucene-not-found) question, I found an answer on google saying that I was suppose to use the autoloader code before I start to use ZendSearch. But I didn't understand that, Can someone explain me what I have to do in details?

Thanks

Comment: would you post your code or detail error information?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667675/zendsearch-install-with-composer-class-zendsearch-lucene-lucene-not-found that's my code